# ExtJS updateLayout is not working

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs5

I am using ExtJS 6 version.

I have panel element and dynamically I am updating panel html as

```
panel.update("<img src=app/resources/first.jpg ></img>");
```

after updating html, image is not loading. I did `panel.updateLayout();` still image is not loading.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The src attribute should be enclosed in quotation marks.

```
  panel.update("<img src='app/resources/first.jpg' ></img>");
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 6 use `setHtml` function instead of `update`:

```
panel.setHtml('<img src=app/resources/first.jpg ></img>');
```

Link to [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/modern/Ext.Panel.html#method-setHtml)